# Post JSON Object to WCF Service Oject always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, wcf, wcf-data-services

Am having trouble with a 'post'.am getting User Object always null.. Im at my wits end and have been researching this for days, so if anyone has any ideas, please help! Thanks in advance

My Jquery looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#register").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //stop the submit event for the submit button
            var Name = $("#register_username").val();
            var Email = $("#register_email").val();
            var Password = $("#register_password").val();
            var Contact = $("#register_contactNumber").val();
            var Adress = "Seteelte Town";
            var chkUserType = document.getElementById("identity_type_2").checked;
            var userinfo = { "request": { "Action": { "Address": Adress, "Children": [], "CityId": 0, "Email": Email, "HomeUser": chkUserType, "ImagePath": "", "IpAdress": "", "IsActive": false, "LastLogin": "", "Name": Name, "Password": Password, "PhoneNumber": Contact, "ProfileHit": 0, "ShowEmail": false, "ShowPhoneNumber": false, "SubscribeNews": false, "UserID": 0}} };

            alert("Input: " + JSON.stringify(userinfo));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Services/Membership.svc/AccountAdd',
                data: JSON.stringify(userinfo),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.Result);
                },
                error: onError
            });
        });
    });
```

My C# code for WCF is

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Membership : IMembership
    {

        public SMProcessResponse<bool> AccountAdd(SMProcess<User> request)
        {
            return new SMProcessResponse<bool>(MembershipController.AccountAdd(request.Action));
        }
}
```

C# code for process request is

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class SMProcess<T> : BaseRequest
    {

        public SMProcess(T obj)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.Action = obj;

        }
        [DataMember]
        public T Action { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my Web.config

```
<configuration>
        <connectionStrings>
   //here is connection string
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SelectionMall.Services.Membership">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Services.webHttpBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SelectionMall.Services.IMembership" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Services.webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why don't you using ScriptMethods?

Comment: @SalientBrain its in requirements..

Comment: Did you enable JSON in your web service? What binding is your service configured to use?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: yes of course.. webHttpBinding in my service

Comment: @DarinDimitrov am going to add web.config in question... may be it exposes issue in true sense

Comment: I was struggling with this as well (related post and others input here): https://stackoverflow.com/a/48906303/826308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your JSON request should be something like this

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AccountAdd", Method = "POST")]
        SMProcessResponse<bool> AccountAdd(SMProcess<User> request);
```

and your JSOn Data

```
var userinfo = { "request": { "Action": { "Address": Adress, "Children": [], "CityId": 0, "Email": "waheed@gmail.com", "HomeUser": true, "ImagePath": "C:/Waheed.jpg", "IpAdress": "192.168.1.3", "IsActive": true, "LastLogin": "\/Date(1358852299323+0500)\/", "Name": "Waheed Iqbal", "Password": "111111", "PhoneNumber": "+923226270150", "ProfileHit": 10, "ShowEmail": true, "ShowPhoneNumber": true, "SubscribeNews": true, "UserID": 1}} }
```

after editing Web.config

```
<behavior name="Services.webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" defaultBodyStyle="WrappedRequest" />
        </behavior>
```

cheers

Comment: @kahloon add defaultBodyStyle="WrappedRequest" in your web.config

Answer (score 1):

You need to have correct [WebInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.aspx) attribute applied to WCF operation. Looking at your JSON request, I believe it should be something like

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json))]
SMProcessResponse<bool> AccountAdd(SMProcess<User> request)
```

Note a wrapped body style (or `WrappedRequest`) is needed so that input JSON would be treated as wrapped one (i.e. parameter name would be the property on incoming JSON).

Apart from this, you might get into issues with your `SMProcess<T>` de-serialization because it does not have any parameter less constructor.

Anyway, I would advise you start with a simple service declaration (and implementation) such as

```
public SMProcessResponse<bool> AccountAdd(User request)
{
   return new SMProcessResponse<bool>(MembershipController.AccountAdd(request));
}
```

And then start adding extra nesting etc.

Comment: this seems that issue is in his web.config